# stop method after 20 second without error in asp Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a action

```
 try
  {
   var db = new GoldDb();
   var groups = await db.Group.Where(m => m.IsActive && m.ManageGroupType != ManageGroupType.Manage).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   if (groups.Any())
    {
      foreach (var group in groups)
        {
          try
           {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
             var uri = new Uri(group.ApiCheckAddress);
             var jsonObject = new { id = group.Id, chatId = group.ChatId };
             var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
             var reponsne = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
             var responseString = await reponsne.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
             var validUserResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseViewModel<List<Int64>>>(responseString,
                                new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

               if (validUserResponse != null && validUserResponse.IsSuccess)
                 {
                   var accountService = new AccountService(db);
                   try
                   {
                     await accountService.CheckChannelMembers(validUserResponse.Data, @group.ChatId, @group.ExecptionDate).ConfigureAwait(false);
                   }
                   catch (Exception e)
                    {
       await Program.BotApi.SendTextMessageAsync(,
                                        "cleared error :" + e.Message);
                     }

                   }
                   else
                    {
                     }
                    }


                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                 await Program.BotApi.SendTextMessageAsync(,
                                        "cleared error :" + e.Message);      
                    }

                }

            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
      await Program.BotApi.SendTextMessageAsync(,
                                        "cleared error :" + e.Message);    
        }
```

and in CheckChannelMembers method, i have a list that remove from telegram channel,
when i run this action, after 20 seconds, The method stops without any error

Comment: How do you know that there are no errors? You are catching them and then not doing anything with the exception. Remove the catch blocks, or re-throw the errors, or log them, or write them to the response.

Comment: I send all catch exeption in telegram bot,

Comment: I suggest you can set breakpoint to `CheckChannelMembers` method and check the `Output` panel to see if contains any stack trace when the method stops.